# Is there any security risk using AWS account alias?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I've used and seen the benefits of [AWS account aliases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html). However, I'm simply curious to know if there's any security risk associated with it, and if not, understand the reasons why not.

I mean, account ID 242541269812 (random number) surely is more difficult to identify as a real AWS account than account alias "myprojectprodenv". Therefore, I get the feeling that an account alias is more exposed to brute-force attacks.

Supposing that someone creates an account alias and doesn't take into account AWS's [IAM best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html) (strong password, adding MFA and not using root account, among others), could that account be under a bigger risk of being hacked by using an account alias?

Maybe I'm being too radical but I'm just curious to know if this could be an actual risk or not.

Thanks!

Comment: If you name your account "test" someone can easily guess it. And if you then choose your password to be "password" then yes, you are a bigger target. But if you rely on your account number to remain private you have bigger issues. You should maybe not willingly post it online but it is not supposed to be part of the defense / security. Instead set up proper IAM permissions, passwords, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awareness of your AWS `Alias`, or even your AWS Account number, does not compromise security of your AWS Account, unless the knowledge of **who you are** would compromise security.

For example, if you use the name of your dog as a password, then knowledge of your Alias or Account Number would compromise the security. However, if you use strong passwords (and preferably MFA), then knowledge of the Alias/Account Number should not impact security.

It would be the equivalent of asking whether knowledge of your email address compromises security of your email archive.